# Mocking threading timer event timeout interval in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, timer, pytest

I am using `threading.Time` in python to recursively calling a function with a set amount of time interval.

I am testing this behaviour via python `pytest` framework.

The problem is that I don't want to wait the time interval until the function is called again (Like 5 seconds in real-time), instead I want to mock the timer interval passed so the function can be called again without having to wait on real-time.

Below is the example to explain in much better way:

```
def main_function(*args):
     def Threading_Time_For_Tasks():
           print("Timer is timeout with 5 seconds")
           threading.Timer(5, Threading_Time).start()

     threading.Timer(5, Threading_Time).start()

     def main_function_wrapper(*args):
           ## Do other task here ##
           return results

     return main_function_wrapper


# This function call will start the timer and will print nothing
# And it will save the wrapper returned function, which can be used
# to pass the values (data) as much as possible
main_function_decorator = main_function(*args)

results1 = main_function_decorator(*args)

results2 = main_function_decorator(*args)
```

After every 5 seconds, it will print the statement infinitely.

```
# 5 seconds have passed
Timer is timeout with 5 seconds

# 5 seconds have passed
Timer is timeout with 5 seconds

....
```

Now, instead of waiting for 5 seconds, I would like to mock 5 seconds and the statement should instantly print the statement.

Any suggestion or idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: first off, if you don't move remove the call to `main_function` from the script it will always run on execution of the tests, no matter what.

Comment: Well, I am using a decorator, will update the script so it is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to my own question.

Apparently, there is a python library which gives you both possibilities; mocking for testing as well as resettable Timer implementation.
The library is the wrapper for `threading.Timer`

Below is the link to the library `resettabletimer`:

https://pypi.org/project/resettabletimer/